# Measuring time spent watching a video with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to track how much time users spend watching videos on our site and what the drop out rate is relative to percent of video duration watched.

I have a counter that increments periodically if the video is running so it holds the total time watched (with little error). Now ideally, I would send this time (and the relation to video length) once users closes the page, but that is [not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onbeforeunload). I ended up sending the event to GA on milestones (namely 0%, 2%, 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 30%, ..., 90%, 95%, 98%, 100%).

Now the thing is, I would like to know what the final event was so I can get the total time watched per day (in GA reports). Should I set unique label for each page view (which I'm not even sure would help that much) or is there something clever I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to do this myself but here is a possible solution:

Try using a scope of [session](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#scope) for [custom dimension/metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#configuration). A session level dimension/metric works in such a way that only the last value is used for the whole session. In your case, just send the progress hits at regular intervals and the last value will be used for your visitor.

Please do reply and tell me if this works. (I think it should.)